How to handle multiple root elements json in a jmeter graphql request?
I have a POST request which contains multiple elements in json.
I get a 400 error with payload:
"extensions":{"code":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR","exception":{"stacktrace":["SyntaxError: Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 44 (line 1 column 45)","   
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

How can I fix this?

Your JSON is not valid, you likely have an extra comma at the end of an object. {"hello":"world",}. Check whatever code generates the JSON on the server

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Although we need to see the JSON response in order to define the problem, but as @NickSlash comment's says, this might be because of invalidation of the JSON.
For example, the JSON below has an extra comma at the end (commas are used to seperate entites in an object. An extra comma at the end makes us to expect for another entity which doesn't exists.):
{
  hello: "world",
  foo: "bar",
}

